# Can't import packages in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I have this error: Assertion failed on expression: '!name.empty()' in Unity when I try to import mixed reality toolkit examples and foundation. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Related issue in their [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/8440). Last comment indicates they will try to fix it for MRTK v3.